# How do I choose which parts of the json file to include in the dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this json right here, I want to create a DF using id as one column, and the fields as the other columns, but not the whole fields, I want a column for message, a column for result, how do I achieve this?

```
[{'id': 'rec6cGAtjL8lmoBgT', 'createdTime': '2022-10-11T22:54:23.000Z', 'fields': {'result': 3, 'message': "Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work done, so it's fine", 'isitweird': True}}, {'id': 'recG1bde9NYyWs9Gm', 'createdTime': '2022-10-12T08:30:20.000Z', 'fields': {'message': "Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work done, so it's fine", 'result': 3, 'isitweird': True}}, {'id': 'rectKvuz20jYYQ7OC', 'createdTime': '2022-10-11T16:39:26.000Z', 'fields': {'result': 5, 'message': 'I am very happy today, it was awesome', 'isitweird': True}}, {'id': 'rectQfHPJZbdDtIpW', 'createdTime': '2022-10-11T22:54:34.000Z', 'fields': {'result': 3, 'message': "Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work done, so it's fine", 'isitweird': True}}, {'id': 'recxbt94M70AjBQS7', 'createdTime': '2022-10-11T22:52:42.000Z', 'fields': {'result': 3, 'message': "Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work done, so it's fine", 'isitweird': True}}, {'id': 'recy1DjwMNOIfuWa6', 'createdTime': '2022-10-11T22:53:56.000Z', 'fields': {'result': 3, 'message': "Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work done, so it's fine", 'isitweird': True}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new list of dicts using flatter function and [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function:

Input:

```
json_input = [{'id': 'rec6cGAtjL8lmoBgT', 'createdTime': '2022-10-11T22:54:23.000Z', 'fields': {'result': 3, 'message': "Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work done, so it's fine", 'isitweird': True}}, {'id': 'recG1bde9NYyWs9Gm', 'createdTime': '2022-10-12T08:30:20.000Z', 'fields': {'message': "Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work done, so it's fine", 'result': 3, 'isitweird': True}}, {'id': 'rectKvuz20jYYQ7OC', 'createdTime': '2022-10-11T16:39:26.000Z', 'fields': {'result': 5, 'message': 'I am very happy today, it was awesome', 'isitweird': True}}, {'id': 'rectQfHPJZbdDtIpW', 'createdTime': '2022-10-11T22:54:34.000Z', 'fields': {'result': 3, 'message': "Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work done, so it's fine", 'isitweird': True}}, {'id': 'recxbt94M70AjBQS7', 'createdTime': '2022-10-11T22:52:42.000Z', 'fields': {'result': 3, 'message': "Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work done, so it's fine", 'isitweird': True}}, {'id': 'recy1DjwMNOIfuWa6', 'createdTime': '2022-10-11T22:53:56.000Z', 'fields': {'result': 3, 'message': "Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work done, so it's fine", 'isitweird': True}}]
```

Script:

```
def flatter(data_row):
    return {'id': data_row['id'], 'result': data_row['fields']['result'], 'message': data_row['fields']['message']}

pd.DataFrame(map(flatter, json_input))
```

Output:

```
    id  result  message
0   rec6cGAtjL8lmoBgT   3   Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work do...
1   recG1bde9NYyWs9Gm   3   Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work do...
2   rectKvuz20jYYQ7OC   5   I am very happy today, it was awesome
3   rectQfHPJZbdDtIpW   3   Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work do...
4   recxbt94M70AjBQS7   3   Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work do...
5   recy1DjwMNOIfuWa6   3   Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work do...
```

Another option is to create a DataFrame and then to apply some functions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_input)
df['message'] = df['fields'].str['message']
df['result'] = df['fields'].str['result']
df = df.drop(columns=['createdTime', 'fields'])
df
```

Output:

```
id  message result
0   rec6cGAtjL8lmoBgT   Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work do...   3
1   recG1bde9NYyWs9Gm   Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work do...   3
2   rectKvuz20jYYQ7OC   I am very happy today, it was awesome   5
3   rectQfHPJZbdDtIpW   Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work do...   3
4   recxbt94M70AjBQS7   Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work do...   3
5   recy1DjwMNOIfuWa6   Today was meh, but I got a good bit of work do...   3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help man, will try in a few hours and then I'll come back here after, but it seems like it works and you really helped me a whoole lot!

Comment: You welcome!
Let me know if you have any other question regarding my answer.

Comment: If something pops up I'll come back here and ask, but it seems to be working in a perfect way, and this snippet of code actually opened my eyes for a bunch of other things that I'll need to do during this project, so again, can't thank you enough, I was going crazy trying to solve this haha